# Load a JSON file and parse it

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to load a JSON file (done) and then parse it in order to access the data to load the links of a Collapsible Force Layout.

```
//Load json from local server
$.getJSON("simulator.json", function(json) {
      console.log(json);
});
```

Comment: What does your json look like?

Comment: [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FJSON%2Fparse), but I think `getJSON` already does that for you...

Comment: Would be nice if you would post what's your problem and how your json looks like.

Comment: How your json looks like?

Comment: The code you have **already parses the JSON**.

Comment: With the funxtion I parse the file, yes? But what i don´t no is how I can acess it, obtain severeal parameters inside it.

Comment: Hoe can I put here a JSFiddle with my json?

Answer (score -1):

Usually the JSON is gone over in a loop like so:

```
for(a in json){
  //see a child object like this
  console.log(json[a]);
  //if it has a property, you can acccess it like so:
  link = json[a].link;
  //if it has child objects you can continue to iterate
  for(b in json[a]){
   console.log(json[a][b]);
  }
}
```